# static linking to libopenblas

Tags: c++, static, openblas

I am compiling a `C++` program with `-static` so that I can take my program to a server and run it. The server has not all libraries installed I am linking with and when trying to run the program I get the error that `libopenblas.so.0` can not be found as `OpenBLAS` is not installed:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I need `OpenBLAS` for the linear algebra library `Armadillo` and I compile with the flags

```
-std=c++11 -static -pthread -Ofast -march=native -mtune=native -m64 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Ishared_methods -Icreate_codes/source_files -Ievaluate_codes/source_files -Igenomes/source_files -lopenblas -llapack -lgfortran
```

So is it not possible to statically link `OpenBLAS` or did I do something wrong?

EDIT: This is my makefile. I have removed the commands and definitions for other programs for simplicity.

```
CXX =       h5c++

CXXFLAGS=   -std=c++11 -static -pthread -Ofast -march=native -mtune=native -m64 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Ishared_methods -Ievaluate_codes/source_files

ENDFLAGS = -lopenblas -llapack -lgfortran

RELDIR_E =  ./evaluate_codes/source_files
RELDIR_M =  ./shared_methods

HEADERS =       $(RELDIR_M)/methods.h   

SRCS_E_MIR =    $(RELDIR_E)/mir.cpp \
        $(RELDIR_M)/methods.cpp

OBJS_E_MIR =    $(SRCS_E_MIR:.cpp=.o)

TARGET_E_MIR = evaluate_codes/mir.out

e_mir:  $(OBJS_E_MIR) 
$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS_E_MIR) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET_E_MIR) $(ENDFLAGS)

clean_e_mir:
rm -f $(OBJS_E_MIR) $(TARGET_E_MIR)
```

EDIT 2: On my machine all the static (`.a`) and shared (`.so`) libraries exist and the program runs, but on the server I do not have all of the libraries. That is why I want to build it fully static, but it seems like the dependencies of the libraries are not fully included as shown by `ldd mir.out`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff74532000)
libopenblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007fe73dbc8000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe73d9ab000)
libsz.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so.2 (0x00007fe73d7a8000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe73d58e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe73d38a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe73d008000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe73ccff000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe73cae9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe73c71f000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fe73c3f4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe73fc5c000)
libaec.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaec.so.0 (0x00007fe73c1ec000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fe73bfad000)
```

So how can I tell the compiler to include those dependencies in a static way?

Comment: Your atempt to statically link your program has been unsuccessful for reasons
we cannot see from what you show us. Please post the *exact* commands you
used to compile and link it, in the body of your question (not in comments).

Comment: Are you sure that all of `libopenblas.a`, `liblapack.a` and `libgfortran.a` exist on the machine? Once you build your binary, you can check what it requires with `ldd`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `-static` option is having no effect.

You have written no rule to compile your source files. You are allowing them to be compiled using make's [built-in rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

```
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $@ S<
```

in which:-

- `$(CXX)` expands to your defined or default C++ compiler
- `$(CPPFLAGS)` expands to your defined Preprocessor flags
- `$(CXXFLAGS)` expands to your defined C++ compiler flags

You have defined:

```
CXXFLAGS=   -std=c++11 -static -pthread -Ofast -march=native -mtune=native \
 -m64 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-long-long \
 -Ishared_methods -Ievaluate_codes/source_files
```

So `-static` is passed to the compilation command by the built-in
recipe.  However, it is not a compilation option. It is a linkage option. It
is ignored in compilation. You do not pass it to the linkage command. So it
has no effect.

Two other important make variables that have conventional meanings to make (and are used
with those meanings in built-in rules) are:

- `LDFLAGS` is to be defined as your linkage options, excluding library options
  (`-lfoo`) and explicitly named libraries
- `LDLIBS` is to be defined as your library options and explicitly named libraries.

So `-static`, a linkage option, should properly be included in the value of `LDFLAGS`, not `CXXFLAGS`

In many ways your makefile deviates from normal practice and suggests you
may not yet be very knowledge about GNU Make. If would be impractical to pick out
all the fluff here. Your linkage recipe is:

```
e_mir:  $(OBJS_E_MIR) 
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS_E_MIR) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET_E_MIR) $(ENDFLAGS)
```

The smallest (though not the best) set of corrections that will cause the `-static`
option to take effect in the linkage is:

- Remove `-static` from the definition of `CXXFLAGS`
- Add it to the definition of `ENDFLAGS`

Be aware that successfully getting `-static` to take effect in the linkage does
not mean that the attempted static linkage will *succeed*: just that it will be
attempted, which is not happening now.

Be aware too that a fully static linkage is a drastic step and is unnecessarily
drastic if the problem you are trying to solve is simply that some shared
libraries you link with are not available on your target server.

The effect of `-static` is require that static versions of *all* the libraries
required by the linkage must be found by your linkage. Not just your:

```
-lopenblas -llapack -lgfortran
```

but also the C runtime library and the Standard C++ library that are linked
by default, plus the Posix Threads library that is requested by `-pthread`.
Have you installed the static versions of all those?

If you merely need to link, say, the static versions of `libopenblas` and `liblapack`, and you have
installed `libopenblas.a` `liblapack.a` on your system so that the linker
will find them in its default search directories, then you can simply change:

```
-lopenblas -llapack -lgfortran
```

to:

```
-l:libopenblas.a -l:liblapack.a -lgfortran
```

Whereas `-lname` instructs the linker to search the specified (`-Ldir`) or
default search directories for either `libname.so` (shared library) or `libname.a`
(static library) and to prefer `libfoo.so` if it finds both in the same directory,
`-l:name` instructs the linker to search for a file with the exact name `name`.
So by specifiying `-l:libopenblas.a` you can request linkage of `libopenblas.a`
with no larger effects than just that.

Comment: Thanks for the general explanation and the fix in my special case!